# Prove that the product of two infinite cyclic groups is not infinite cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am very sorry that I deleted my previous post on this same topic and specially to **@lhf**, since I forced him/her to delete his/her answer.

> Prove that the product of two infinite cyclic groups is not infinite cyclic.

The part I did:

$G=<a>$ and $G'=<b>$. The product group is $G\times G'$, where mulplication rule is $$(a^{k_1},b^{l_1}),(a^{k_2},b^{l_2})\rightsquigarrow (a^{k_1+k_2},b^{l_1+l_2})$$ where $k_1,k_2,l_1,l_2\in \mathbb{Z}$

Now suppose the cyclic group $G\times G'$ is generated by $(a^k,b^l)$

Then for any $m,n\neq 0$, $(a^m,b^n)=(a^{ku},b^{lu})\Rightarrow \frac{k}{l}=\frac{m}{n}$, which can not be true since $k,l$ are fixed and $G,G'$ are infinite cyclic group.

But then I am **stuck**. What should be the lat argument to end this proof!

Comment: I have undeleted your previous post.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff why would you do that!!! What is the meaning have 2 posts on same topic?

Comment: The answer by lhf is perfectly valid. Remember, we prefer not to delete posts. You can always edit a post if you think you have given an incorrect definition, deleting them after someone has provided a useful answer is not the way to go.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff you are right! thanks...

Comment: Answered at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379053/prove-that-the-product-of-two-infinite-cyclic-groups-is-not-infinite-cyclic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a group $G$ is cyclic, then the following assertion is clearly satisfied:
$$\forall x,y \in G \backslash \{1 \}, \ \exists n,m \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0 \}, \ x^n=y^m.$$
Thus, in order to prove that the product of two infinite cyclic groups (ie., $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$) is not cyclic, it is sufficient to notice that
$$n(1,0)=(n,0) \neq (0,m) = m(0,1)$$
for every $n,m \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $G\times G'$ is generated by $a^kb^l$, this implies that $a^nb^n=(a^kb^l)^p=a^{kp}b^{lp}$. We deduce that $n=kp, n=lp$ and $n$ is a multiple of $k$ and $l$. This implies that $k=l=1$. Now $a^2b^3$ is not in $(ab)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $G$ and $G'$ are infinite groups. 
Let $g\in G$ and suppose that $(g,e')=(a,a')^{k}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $a^{-k}=e'\Rightarrow \langle a'\rangle$ forms a finite subgroup of $G'$. Pick $g'\notin \langle a'\rangle \Rightarrow (g,g')\notin \langle (a,a')\rangle$. The inference is that there can be no generator.