# Proof for $Z^2$ not being cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Heres my proof for $Z^2$ not being a cyclic group can anyone confirm if this looks good.

Let $Z^2=\{ (a,b):a,b∈Z \}$

Since $Z^2$ is additive group, if it were cyclic there must be a fixed p,q such that $k(p,q) = (a,b)$ for any $ a,b∈Z$. So $(p,q) = (\frac{a}{k},\frac{b}{k})$. But if k doesnt divide a,b $(p,q)$ wont be integers and therefore not in the group so not cyclic.

Can anyone confirm if this is a valid proof

Comment: But this same idea would show $\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: K is multiplying the generator because Z is additive so it would be (p,q) + (p,q) + .... for any K

Comment: Regard $\Bbb{Z}^2$ as a two-dimensional vector space.  Any cyclic subgroup is one-dimensional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379053/prove-that-the-product-of-two-infinite-cyclic-groups-is-not-infinite-cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

If $k(p,q)=(a,b)$ then $k$ must divide both $a,b$. What can you say about $(p,q)$ if you try to generate, say, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct. The assertion “if it were cyclic there must be a fixed $(p,q)$ such that $k(p,q) = (a,b)$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb Z$” is meaningless, since you say nothing about $k$.

Comment: I've let (p,q) be added to itself k times because it would be the generator of the additive Z group so ive multiplied by K for any K

Comment: @NoteBook And the sentence that I quoted is still meaningless.

Comment: Jose-- It would make sense if it were quantified. Say fixed $(p,q)$ such that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $(a,b)=k(p,q).$